# Identify similar repeating ascending patterns in numeric vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, pattern-matching, repeat

I have multiple numeric vectors that have a similar repeating ascending pattern. eg:

```
vec_1 <- c(43, 17, 186, 193, 186, 186, 474, 491, 498, 498, 673, 736, 743, 716, 
           44, 19, 193, 194, 193, 193, 472, 498, 476, 499, 673, 743, 714, 714, 
           19, 21, 194, 180, 194, 194, 485, 499, 481, 476, 712, 719, 712, 
           17, 40, 174, 180, 169, 495, 485, 673, 177, 485, 481, 714, 730, 733, 
           40, 33, 190, 174, 180, 482, 495, 495, 479, 703, 733, 704)
```

There are always 5 repetitions. In above example:

1. starts with 43, ends with 716
2. starts with 44 (where 1. ends), ends with 714
3. etc.

I want to generate a new vector that identifies the repetition number. For vec_1 this would be:

```
rep_nums_1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
                2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, ..., 5)
```

The number of items within each repetition can differ (so I cant just assign the first 14 elements as 1, the next 14 as 2, etc.)

Not sure how best to approach this. A non elegant solution would be to check if the next element in the sequence is smaller than the current by more than e.g. 300 and change the group number if so. Any better suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: i may be dense but it seems you're glossing over a lot of essential information in step 3.

Comment: 3 refers to repetition number 3 (all five of which start with a low number and end with a high number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for some more elaboration on whence your "pattern", but I think this does the trick:

```
rep(1:5, diff(c(0, which(diff(vec_1) < -500), length(vec_1))))
```

There should be an approach with `rle` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant would be

```
cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(vec_1) < -500))
```